# what is the best database files that could be used to save "dataset" from a "datagridview" locally

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

So, i use VB.NET, in my DataGridView i have a checkboxcolumn, an imagecolumn and so there are some textboxcolumns.

And i just want to save values locally.

For checkboxcolumn, it was easy to save Cells.Value.ToString, but ImageColumn i have no idea how to save the image location.

i mean, how to save DataGridViewImageCell.value to my database file as image location or something?

and, Any suggestions about the type of database files should i use?

And thanks.

Please see:

- i have no problem if i have to keep images in project resources or just put them in the start up directory
- and so i have no problem even if i should make it a data bound control

Comment: Are the images large? is there a maximum data size or image size?

Comment: @bendataclear no, images about 25x25 only